# Comparing two lists and popping the larger value to a new list (Python)

Tags: python

I have to compare two lists and add the top value to a new list. I want to use the .pop function with my code I have now. This is homework but all my resources have been shut down so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my code if it helps.

```
class topList():
    __slots__ = ( "name", "gender", "occurences" )

def mkList( name, gender, occurences ):
    find = topList()
    find.name = name
    find.gender = gender
    find.occurences = occurences
    return find

def main():
    year = input( 'Enter year: ' )
    file = open( 'yob' + year + '.txt' )
    lst = []
    femaleLst = []
    maleLst = []
    for line in file:
        line1 = line.split( "," )
        names = mkList( line1[0], line1[1], line1[2] )
        lst.append( names )
        if names.gender == 'F':
            femaleLst += [ line1 ]
        else:
            maleLst += [ line1 ]
    while len( lst ) < 20:
        if name.occurences( maleLst ) > name.occurences( femaleLst ):
            maleLst.pop(0) += [ lst ]
        else:
            femaleLst.pop(0) += [ lst ]
    print( femaleLst )


main()
```

Comment: Why not use a namedtuple instead of that class?

Comment: My assignment requires me to create my own class

Comment: It's stupid to use a class for the sake of using a class. :)

Comment: Put some comments in your code to describe what it is doing - especially that while loop at the bottom of main().  Are you getting an error/exception?